# What is the casting level of magic items? eg, Javelin of lightning

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

I notice there are a lot of similar questions about, but none for 5e.

So, a high level sorcerer is inside a Globe of Invulnerability cast at 6th level. Suddenly, they are hit by the lightning strike from the Javelin of Lightning. I know the globe only stops spells that are cast, but technically the thrower did utter a magic command word which turned it into a spell that was cast.

Therefore, can it be blocked by the globe?

Comment: Can you either clarify the question or the body? You ask a general question, but the body has a very specific one. Which would you like answered? There are very different answers for the two.

Comment: I assumed that if there was an answer for the specific question then it would answer the general one. Since there is no casting level for wonderous items, both questions are answered.

Comment: It's not about Wonderous items not having a casting level - it's that the Javelin of Lightning does not  involve a spell. AND that for items that DO cast a spell, it's what Miniman wrote below OR dictated by the item.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The *javelin of lightning*'s special effect is not a spell. Anything that is a spell uses the word "spell" to indicate that. So *Globe of Invulnerability* will not block a *javelin of lightning*. Jeremy Crawford was asked about the (extremely similar) *staff of thunder and lightning*, and gave [the same answer](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/12/19/how-does-globe-of-invulnerability-interact-with-an-item-like-staff-of-thunder/).

With that said, the rule for spells cast from magic items is on page 141 of the DMG:

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item. **The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level**, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, unless the item's description says otherwise.

So if you used an item that allows you to cast *lightning bolt*, rather than the *javelin of lightning*, the *lightning bolt* would be cast as a 3rd-level spell, since that is the lowest spell level at which *lightning bolt* can be cast.